# list index out of range by parsing file

Tags: python

I have the following input file:

```
cluster = 1 | chr = 4 and pos between 2758711 and 2758981
o   4   -   2758729 seq_5128695|3   TTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTAC    20  3   n=53    k=12    hts=2   2758876 4.16686934332199e-07
o   4   -   2758729 seq_5128699|24  TTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTACC   21  24  n=53    k=12    hts=2   2758876 4.16686934332199e-07
o   4   +   2758753 seq_4551617|12  TCTCATTTTGACGTTTGTGCA   21  12  n=96    k=16    hts=1   2758753 1.02477225265282e-07
o   4   -   2758771 seq_2925847|28  CACAAACGTCAAAATGAGATC   21  28  n=96    k=16    hts=1   2758753 1.02477225265282
o   4   -   2758981 seq_4939296|10  TTCGTAGGCTGGAAGAGAGGA   21  10  n=96    k=16    hts=1   2758753 1.02477225265282e-07

cluster = 1 | chr = 4 and pos between 2758711 and 2758981
o   4   -   2758729 seq_5128695|3   TTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTAC    20  3   n=53    k=12    hts=2   2758876 4.16686934332199e-07
o   4   -   2758729 seq_5128699|24  TTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTACC   21  24  n=53    k=12    hts=2   2758876 4.16686934332199e-07
o   4   +   2758753 seq_4551617|12  TCTCATTTTGACGTTTGTGCA   23  12  n=96    k=16    hts=1   2758753 1.02477225265282e-07
```

From the above file, I would like to keep only rows which contain on 6th position a 21.

```
def run(clust, length, out):
    with open(clust) as clust_fn:

        for line in clust_fn:
            try:
                parts = line.split('\t')
            except IndexError:
                print("!!!", parts)
                break

            print(parts)
            print(parts[6])
            if int(parts[6])==length:
                print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run("input.txt", 21, "out.bed")
```

Unfortunately, the above code caused:

```
  File "phasis2bed.py", line 28, in run
    print(parts[6])
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I don't see any tabs.

Comment: One can add the tabs, of course, if they are implied (e.g. in `notepad++`:`edit`:`blank operations`:`space to tab (leading)`). Then just print your output.

Comment: Why not use the CSV module for this?

Comment: How it would you do it with CSV?

Answer (score 0):

The `.split('\t')` will never throw an error. As a result, your code is failing because of the first line of your file. Instead, try this:

```
for line in clust_fn:
    if "\t" not in parts:
        continue
    parts = parts.split("\t")
    print(parts)
    print(parts[6])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the output a list so it's easier to see the tabs.
Assuming that you actually have the tabs (see my comment above), you can do this:

```
def run(clust, length):
    outlist=[]
    with open(clust) as clust_fn: 
         for line in clust_fn:             
            parts = line.split('\t')

            try:
                if parts[5]!=None:
                    print(parts[5])
                    if parts[5]==str(length):
                        outlist.append(line)
            except:
                print('_') 
    return outlist


outlist=run("c:/pddata/temp.txt", 21 )
```

output:

```
['o\t4\t-\t2758729 seq_5128699|24\tTTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTACC\t21\t24\tn=53\tk=12\thts=2\t2758876 4.16686934332199e-07\n',
 'o\t4\t+\t2758753 seq_4551617|12\tTCTCATTTTGACGTTTGTGCA\t21\t12\tn=96\tk=16\thts=1\t2758753 1.02477225265282e-07\n',
 'o\t4\t-\t2758771 seq_2925847|28\tCACAAACGTCAAAATGAGATC\t21\t28\tn=96\tk=16\thts=1\t2758753 1.02477225265282\n',
 'o\t4\t-\t2758981 seq_4939296|10\tTTCGTAGGCTGGAAGAGAGGA\t21\t10\tn=96\tk=16\thts=1\t2758753 1.02477225265282e-07\n',
 'o\t4\t-\t2758729 seq_5128699|24\tTTTCCCTACTTTTGTCTTACC\t21\t24\tn=53\tk=12\thts=2\t2758876 4.16686934332199e-07\n']
```